# Initialize value of self in the standartd class accessor

Tags: ruby

How I can do something like this:

```
class Some < String
    def m1(a, b)
        self = a + b
    end
end

s = Some.new("hello")
s.m1("one ", "two")
p s # => "one two"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how exactly you define "something like".

If you want to make it so that all variables that point to the given `Some` object, now instead point to the string that is the result of `a + b`, that's not possible.

If you want to change the string contents of the given `Some` object, you can use the `replace` method, i.e. `replace(a+b)`.

To illustrate the difference between using `replace` and reassignment:

```
class Some < String
    def m1(a, b)
        replace( a + b )
    end
end

s1 = Some.new("hello")
p s1.object_id # some number
s1.m1("one ", "two")
p s1 # "one two"
p s1.object_id # the same number as above
p s1.class # Some

s2 = Some.new("hello")
p s2.object_id # some number
s2 = "one " + "two"
p s2 # "one two"
p s2.object_id # a different number
p s2.class # String
```

The latter behavior is not achievable using a method.

Comment: @demas You'll get that output when using `replace`. The question is whether you just want to change the contents of the `Some` object that `s` points to (which replace does) or you want `s` to actually point somewhere else (i.e. the same behavior as if you did `s = "one" + "two"`. The latter is not possible.

Comment: It works fine but I am searching more general solution. For example, I need solution for Some < Array.  Num class doesn't have replace method.

Comment: @demas You can't do anything like this for numbers. It's just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby have `delegate` in standart library for this situations. You can
safely override standart classes. It is recommended using `!` in
destructive method names.

```
require 'delegate'

class MyStr < DelegateClass(String)
  def initialize dnm=""
    @str = dnm
    super(@str)
  end

  def m1!(a,b)
    @str.replace(a + b)
  end
end

s = MyStr.new("deneme")
s.m1!("de", "ne")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
class Some < String
    def m1(a, b)
        self.clear << a << b
    end
end

some = Some.new("bye")
some.m1("hello ","world")
p some #=>hello world
```

Comment: The doesn't lead to the behavior the OP described. This will add to the string, not replace it. Note that in his example code the output is "one two", not "helloone two".